# Create floating text box like Gmail using google material design lite

Tags: html, css, material-design, material-design-lite

I am using the Material design lite library and trying to create a Floating text box like what google has for the Gmail. I didn't find any documentation for the component, however I tried the below code

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label has-placeholder">
     <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample5" placeholder="">
     <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample5">Text lines...</label>
</div>
```

This creates a design something like this

[image]

I am trying to design the text box something like this

[image]

Is there any way to create this design ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I created:

```
<div id="googleLogIn" style="position:absolute;">
 <input type="text" style="border:6px solid blue;height:35px;width:300px;position:absolute;top:50px;" 
 placeholder="">
 <p style="background-color:white;width:100px;position:absolute;left:20px;top:25px;padding:3px;">
 Email or phone</p>
</div>
```

It makes something close to what you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Try using HTML tags feildset and legend:

```
<span style="font-family:arial;font-size:.9em">
    <fieldset style="width:300px;border-color:blue;border-radius:5px;padding:10px">
    <legend style="color:blue">&nbsp;Email or phone&nbsp;</legend>
    <input type="text" style="border:0;font-size:2em">
    </fieldset><br>
</span>
<span style="font-family:arial;color:blue;font-weight:bold">Forgot email?</span>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes